# How to make file check for two input strings?

Tags: php, html, input, match

At the moment, I am trying to build a very simple file check code that requires two inputs to be checked as files:

```html
<?php
    if (file_exists($_POST['input1'] . '.html')) &&(file_exists($_POST['input2'] . '.txt')) {
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/exists");
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/noexist);
    }
?>
```

The code should search the folder for two files with names of whatever 'input1' and 'input2' were entered as (1 being an html file and 2 being a txt), but it returns a blank screen.

Comment: Typo in end of second header. Write `"`

Comment: Hi you should give full file path in `file_exists()` to check. if you are only passing filename then this will not work.

Comment: @LuckySaini Are you sure about that? I'd think it would check the same path the calling script is in if you only give it a filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some error in your code missing `"` in else condition and you should used complete path of your file instead of file name

All issues has been fixed

```
$path= '/your_file_path/'; 
if (file_exists($path.$_POST['input1'] . '.html') && file_exists($path.$_POST['input2'] . '.txt'))  
{ 
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/exists"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/noexist");
}
```

the better way to use this

```
$path1='/your_file_path/'.$_POST['input1'] . '.html';
$path2='/your_file_path/'.$_POST['input2'] . '.txt';

if (file_exists($path1) && file_exists($path2))
```

some more details to use absolute path

```
$file_name=$_POST['input1'] . '.html';
$path= dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$file_name}";
```

Some more information about absolute path and relative path

- If the path is built starting from the system root, it is called absolute.
- If the path is built starting from the current location, it is called relative

[Reference OR more details about absolute and relative path](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths)

For more details about [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function

Comment: "_you should used complete path of your file instead of file name_" Unless I'm completely missing something, this is not true. `if ( file_exists('.345345.ico') ) {
    echo "exists";
}` works as expected and prints out "exists" if there is a file called `.345345.ico` in the same folder as the script this code is in.

Comment: @kerbholz some time relative path conflicts in php function then we used absolute path.

Comment: Ok, "_some time relative path conflicts in php function_" Never had any trouble with relative paths (unless the relative paths were incorrect, which is not `file_exists()`s fault). LuckySainis comment and your "_you should used complete path of your file instead of file name_" make it sound like that's the reason why OPs code doesn't work and using only a filename in `file_exists()` is not allowed. Nevermind